# Nested RecyclerView with Horizontal Scroll

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I'm trying to implement nested `RecyclerView`s with 3 layers. The 1st `RecyclerView` (parent) view is set to scroll vertically. The 2nd `RecyclerView` (child of the 1st) view is set to scroll horizontally. The 3rd `RecyclerView` (child of the 2nd) view is also set to scroll horizontally.

To visualize:

-> `RecyclerView` with vertical scroll
--> `RecyclerView` with horizontal scroll
---> `RecyclerView` with horizontal scroll

Now, the problem is I can't make the 3rd horizontal RecyclerView scroll horizontally. I think the problem is the device is prioritising the horizontal scroll of the 2nd `RecyclerView`.

Can you help me solve this issue?

This is the snippet code for the layout of the 1st one with vertical scrolling:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"            
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is for the 2nd one with horizontal scrolling:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"            
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is for the last one with horizontal scrolling:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I already tried intercepting the touch with `onIntercept...()` to cancel the scrolling of the 2nd `RecyclerView` while the 3rd is being touched.

Comment: Even if you manage to make it work, having a scrollable horizontal list inside another scrollable horizontal list sounds like a bad idea, let alone having both lists inside a third one that is also scrollable. Are you sure there aren't any design changes you can make to avoid doing this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I can't make changes to the design anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NestedScrollViewHome  extends NestedScrollView {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int slop;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private float mInitialMotionX;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private float mInitialMotionY;
    public NestedScrollViewHome(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
    private void init(Context context) {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
        slop = config.getScaledEdgeSlop();
    }
    public NestedScrollViewHome(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }
    public NestedScrollViewHome(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                              int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }
    private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
                lastX = ev.getX();
                lastY = ev.getY();
                // This is very important line that fixes
                computeScroll();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final float curX = ev.getX();
                final float curY = ev.getY();
                xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
                yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
                lastX = curX;
                lastY = curY;
                if (xDistance > yDistance) {
                    return false;
                }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    public interface OnScrollChangedListener {
        void onScrollChanged(NestedScrollView who, int l, int t, int oldl,
                             int oldt);
    }
    private OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener;
    public void setOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener listener) {
        mOnScrollChangedListener = listener;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mOnScrollChangedListener != null) {
            mOnScrollChangedListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which layer should I use this custom `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: in place of <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView use NestedScrollViewHome